# SQL Developer Trigger

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am running out of ideas to solve this. I am working on a homework assignment and I can't figure out how to check if returndate - duedate > 12 hours

P.S. I have added the preference to use time.

Here is the problem

- Create a trigger named trg_late_return that will write the correct value to DETAIL_DAYSLATE in the DETAILRENTAL table whenever a video is returned.  The trigger should execute as a BEFORE trigger when the DETAIL_RETURNDATE or DETAIL-DUEDATE attributes are updated.  The trigger should satisfy the following conditions:

  1. If the return date is null, then the days late should also be null.
  2. If the return date is not null, then the days late should determine if the video is returned late.
  3. If the return date is noon of the date after the return or earlier, then the video is not considered late, and the days late should have a value of zero.
  4. If the return date is past noon of the day after the due date, then the video is considered late, so the number of days late must be calculated and stored.
  5. The "before noon" grace period applies to returns on the next day only. Any returns after the grace period count as a full day late. Consider the following examples:

     - Example 1: Due 1/1/14 returned 1/2/14 before noon then not late.
     - Example 2: Due 1/1/14 returned 1/2/14 after noon then late 1 day.
     - Example 3: Due 1/1/14 returned 1/4/14 anytime then 3 days late

My current Trigger looks like this

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRG_LATE_RETURN 
BEFORE UPDATE OF DETAIL_RETURNDATE,DETAIL_DUEDATE ON DETAILRENTAL 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
  IF :NEW.DETAIL_RETURNDATE <> NULL THEN
    IF :NEW.DETAIL_RETURNDATE - DETAILRENTAL.DETAIL_DUEDATE > TO_CHAR (sysdate +12/24, 'HH24:MI:SS') THEN
      UPDATE DETAILRENTAL
      SET DETAILRENTAL.DETAIL_DAYSLATE = DETAIL_RETURNDATE - DETAIL_DUEDATE;
    ELSE
      UPDATE DETAILRENTAL
      SET DETAILRENTAL.DETAIL_DAYSLATE = 0;
    END IF;
  END IF;
END;
```

This doesn't work by the way. I don't know how to check the time.

Comment: I had to update the question posting because it was messy and not readable.

Comment: I figured out that I needed to do this. To_CHAR(:NEW.DETAIL_RETURNDATE, 'HH24:MI:SS') <= '12:00:00') so I fixed my block of code to make that work.